# Round Decimals Within Complex Math Calculation

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

I have a variable I've been working on which I can't seem to output the way I would like it to. Here is the variable I currently have:

```
var resource1RatePerHour = Math.ceil(resource1BaseRate1 * Math.pow(resourceIncomeModifier, resource1BuildingLevel) +30) / 3600;
```

Now this is called on a increment timer every second, though has to be calculated as a per hourly gain (hence the division by 3600).

This all seems to work however my issue is that there are now many trailing digits which I would like removed, preferably not using a trim method. Before (using Math.ceil) I wouldn't get any decimals. If I add the "/ 3600" within the Math.ceil equation the whole calculation will not work, so it has to stay outside both Math.ceil and Math.pow.

Comment: I guess [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) is what you looking for

Comment: That would work, if I wanted 2 decimals. :) 55.67 should output 55 in such an example. So unless I misunderstand toFixed?

Comment: @hindmost you were initially correct with toFixed, I had no idea you could pass along an argument to specify the amount of decimals to show. I've put together a work-around using the answer provided by Yeldar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript `toFixed()` function:

```js
var x = 123.45 * 234.56;

document.body.innerHTML += x.toFixed(0) + "<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML += x.toFixed(1) + "<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML += x.toFixed(2) + "<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML += x.toFixed(3) + "<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML += x.toFixed(4) + "<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML += x.toFixed(5) + "<br/>";
```

Comment: Thanks, this, with a bit of modification, worked for me! I never knew you could pass an argument to toFixed like that, to display the amount of decimals that you want. Any downside to using this? I'm currently using:

`document.getElementById("HTML_resource1Ticker").innerHTML = resource1Ticker.toFixed(2);`

Comment: @Deadmano None, that's what this function is supposed to do. It also works fine in all browsers. Note that this function returns a string but not a number.

Comment: It is perfect for my needs! On a side note, don't want to open up another question for something trivial, do you have any idea how I could transform a number such as "93958769423.9" (which is 93,958,769,423) to using a B (billion) separator? So in this specific case the number would be 93B, or 94B rounded up.

I would truly appreciate it, and if you could share how I could do the same for K, M and even T (trillion). As I am working with exponentials and they can get insanely high!

Comment: @Deadmano I guess, you will have to open a new question. That's how it works. I will try to help you after it, and other people will also be able to answer it. Shortly said, I think that you will have to implement it manually, I don't know any such function in JS.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to display it in a nice format, converting to a string will remove them I think.

```
var x = 1.245000
var niceDisplay = x.toString() // "1.245"
```